# Play framework scala - run same integration tests against 2 servers

Tags: java, scala, unit-testing, playframework, integration-testing

I'm working on something where we have around 30 different `Spec` files for integration tests. Each of these files launches one server before running.

It uses the play framework's `FakeApplication` object from the package `play.api.test` to do that.(overriding `newAppForTest`

Now I want to make all these tests run against 2 different servers instead of 1, passing `config1` and `config2` while starting the `FakeApplication`

Is there a simple way to accomplish this?
One way is definitely to have all these 30 files in another package where I launch the server with the `config2`.